# return multiple column data from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a functional query, however, I now need to add an additional column that would display data from one of the sub-queries.  Im a bit stuck on how to do this.

Ive considered modifying the existing sql into a join type query, but have been unsuccessful.

```
--
select case when max(intid) != min(intid) then max(intid) end as INTID_NEW,min(intid) as INTID_PREV
from   DFUND
where   ANum in
    (select ANum from DFUND              
        where intid in
            (select intid as pair
            from AReview
            where Rule = 3366
            and trunc(RECVDDATE) >= trunc(sysdate-4) 
                        )
    )
group by ANum
order by ANum;
--
```

### Here is what the current query returns

```
 INTID_NEW INTID_PREV
---------- ----------
   4421156    3450805
   4426479    3174829
```

--

### I would like it to return the following:

```
 INTID_NEW INTID_PREV RECVDDATE
---------- ---------- -----------
   4421156    3450805 01-MAY-2019
   4426479    3174829 04-MAY-2019
```

--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use INNER JOIN instead of IN clause  and select from the subquery also the column you need

```
    select case when max(intid) != min(intid) then max(intid) end as INTID_NEW, min(intid) as INTID_PREV, t.my_RECVDDATE 
    from   DFUND
    INNER JOIN (
        select ANum,  t2.my_RECVDDATE
        from D  
        INNER JOIN   (
          select intid , trunc(RECVDDATE) as my_RECVDDATE
                from AReview
                where Rule = 3366
                and trunc(RECVDDATE) >= trunc(sysdate-4) 
          ) t2 ON t2.intid =  DFund.intid
    ) t on t.ANum = DFUND.ANum 
    group by ANum,  t.my_RECVDDATE 
    order by ANum;
```

Comment: Hello, I get the following error: --ERROR at line 11:
ORA-00904: "T2"."INTID": invalid identifier--